# how to display dynamic spinner values in android

Tags: android, spinner

In the code below, I took two spinners. One is for brand and other for model. But data is not being displaying in spinner. It is not showing any errors but dropdown is also not shown.

Can any one help me?
What is the mistake in the code?

**Java**

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}
    Fragment fragment = null;

    String userId,companyId;
    private String brandid = "3";
    public static List<LeadResult.Users> list;
    public static List<BrandResult.Brands> listBrands;
    public static List<ModelResult.Models> listModels;
    public static ArrayList<String> listBrands_String;
   // public static List<BrandResult.Brands> list1;
    String[] brand_name;
    Spinner spinner1;
    private  RelativeLayout mRel_Ownview,mRel_publicview;
    private  LinearLayout mLin_Stock,mLin_Contact;
    private TextView mTxt_OwnView,mTxt_PublicView;
    private Map<String, String> BrandMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private  RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar;
    private  RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ActionBar actionBar=getActivity().getActionBar();

        actionBar.setTitle("DEVINE MECHINES");

        SharedPreferences userPreference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("UserDate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        userId=userPreference.getString("MYID", null);
        companyId=userPreference.getString("companyId",null);


        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ownview, container, false);
        spinner1=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.brand1);
        mTxt_OwnView=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_OwnView);
        mTxt_PublicView =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_PublicView);
        mRel_Ownview=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ownview);
        mRel_publicview =(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.publicview);

        listBrands = new ArrayList<BrandResult.Brands>();

        listBrands_String = new ArrayList<String>();
        listModels = new ArrayList<ModelResult.Models>();

        seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(5000, 50000,getActivity());
        seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                // handle changed range values
                //Log.i(TAG, "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);
                TextView seekMin = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textSeekMin);
                TextView seekMax = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textSeekMax);
                seekMin.setText(minValue.toString());
                seekMax.setText(maxValue.toString());
            }
        });

        seekBar1 = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(5000, 50000,getActivity());
        seekBar1.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                // handle changed range values
                //Log.i(TAG, "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);
                TextView seekMin = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textSeekMin1);
                TextView seekMax = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textSeekMax1);
                seekMin.setText(minValue.toString());
                seekMax.setText(maxValue.toString());
            }
        });


        mTxt_OwnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mRel_publicview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTxt_OwnView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
                mTxt_PublicView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_blue));
                mTxt_OwnView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_white));
                mTxt_PublicView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
                mRel_Ownview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });

        mTxt_PublicView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mRel_Ownview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTxt_PublicView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
                mTxt_OwnView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_blue));
                mTxt_OwnView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
                mTxt_PublicView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_white));
                mRel_publicview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });


        String selectedBrandId = BrandMap.get(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));


      // System.out.print(url);



        mLin_Stock=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.stock);

        mLin_Stock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fragment =new StockFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();


            }
        });
        mLin_Contact =(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts);
        mLin_Contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                // getLead();
                fragment = new ContactFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                getLead();

            }
        });

// add RangeSeekBar to pre-defined layout

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_seek);
        layout.addView(seekBar);

        ViewGroup layout1 = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_seek1);
        layout1.addView(seekBar1);

        getBrands();
        getModels();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void getBrands() {

       String brandjson = JSONBuilder.getJSONBrand();
        String brandurl = URLBuilder.getBrandUrl();

        Log.d("url", "" + brandurl);
        SendToServerTaskBrand taskBrand = new SendToServerTaskBrand(getActivity());
        taskBrand.execute(brandurl, brandjson);
        //Log.d("brandjson", "" + brandjson);


    }

    private void setBrand(String brandjson)
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper_brand = new ObjectMapper();

        try

         {
            BrandResult brandresult_object = objectMapper_brand.readValue(brandjson, BrandResult.class);

            String Brand_result = brandresult_object.getRESULT();
            Log.i("Brand_result","Now" + Brand_result);


            if(Brand_result.equals("SUCCESS"))
            {
                listBrands =brandresult_object.getBRANDS();
                Log.i("listbrands", "List Brands" + listBrands);

               /* for(int i = 0; i < listBrands.size(); i++){

                    listBrands_String.add(listBrands.get(i).toString());
                    Log.d("string is",""+ listBrands_String);
                }*/

                spinner_fn();



                // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Contact_Activity.class));

            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return eNames;

    }

    public class SendToServerTaskBrand extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTaskBrand(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String Burl = params[0];
            String Bjson = params[1];
            String Bresult = UrlRequester.post(mContext, Burl, Bjson);

            return Bresult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setBrand(result);
            Log.i("Result","Brand Result"+result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }


    private void getModels() {

        String model_url = URLBuilder.getModelUrl();
        String model_json = JSONBuilder.getJSONModel(brandid);

        Log.d("model_json", "" + model_json);
        SendToServerTaskModel taskModel = new SendToServerTaskModel(getActivity());
        taskModel.execute(model_url, model_json);


    }

    private void setModel(String json)
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapperModel = new ObjectMapper();

        try
        {
            ModelResult modelresult_object = objectMapperModel.readValue(json, ModelResult.class);
            String model_result = modelresult_object.getRESULT();
            Log.d("model_result","" + model_result);


            if (model_result.equals("SUCCESS"))
            {
                listModels =modelresult_object.getMODELS();

                Log.i("listmodels", " " + listModels);


                // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Contact_Activity.class));

            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return eNames;

    }

    public class SendToServerTaskModel extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTaskModel(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String url = params[0];
            String json = params[1];
            String result = UrlRequester.post(mContext, url, json);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setModel(result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }


    private void spinner_fn() {


        /*ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                listBrands_String, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);*/

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listBrands_String);

       // ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


        //dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new",""+ listBrands_String.get(position));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

    }

    private void getLead()
    {

        String url = URLBuilder.getLeadUrl();
        String json = JSONBuilder.getJSONLead(userId, companyId);
        SendToServerTask task = new SendToServerTask(getActivity());
        task.execute(url, json);

    }


    private void setLead(String json)
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try
        {
            LeadResult result_object = objectMapper.readValue(json, LeadResult.class);

            String lead_result = result_object.getRESULT();
            Log.d("lead_result","" + lead_result);


            if (lead_result.equals("SUCCESS"))
            {
                list=result_object.getUSERS();
               // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Contact_Activity.class));
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return eNames;

    }
    public class SendToServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTask(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String url = params[0];
            String json = params[1];
            String result = UrlRequester.post(mContext, url, json);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setLead(result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are getting the values in arrayadapter.

Comment: Did you debug that listBrands_String is filled up when the spinner_fn() method is called? I'm not sure how the adapter holds the reference of the model array. It can be that it is a clone. So which would mean you have to initialize your adapter on a class field and then in your async task when the model data comes in, push them in the adapter.

Comment: it's not going inside if it is success means

Comment: **Have you ever heard about `"Code Reusability" `?** First thing you should do is that learn what is that and how to use that. I can see 3 asynctTask classes. That's very bad use of OOPs concepts.

Comment: yes i replaced ........

Comment: yes I am getting values in arrayadapter